# I am not able to boot in ASUS X541UAK

Tags: boot

I was trying to boot my laptop with ubuntu 20 ,While booting when i choose option for ubuntu installation then my screen black out and error =5 and relevadation error=5 is showing continuous form then ubuntu started and when i choose to connect with wifi then again same happens and never stop.

Comment: Welcome! Please specify what the message actually says rather than its code number, and add any other error messages / boot process messages you find relevant. Please edit your question and add as much information as you can so we can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

adding pci=nomsi on the same line where quiet and splash appear seem to help.
On the Grub boot menu press "e" to edit and scroll down to the second last line.
Hope it help